# iptables icmp-host-prohibited

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm having trouble with my iptables. My virtual Machine cannot ping 8.8.8.8 but, it can ping the default gateway. I've tried deleting the rules that are rejecting ICMP in FORWARD and INPUT chain and, still have a problem.

My VM iptables rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Feb 19 11:20:36 2018
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [34:5269]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.56.0/24 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state 
NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.56.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb 19 11:20:36 2018
```

My host machine has these following rules configured:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Feb 19 16:01:15 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8:752]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb 19 16:01:15 2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure what your question really is. And you need to further define your interfaces both on the VM and on the host and the settings of your vm network. Are you NATting your traffic outbound? Can your host ping 8.8.8.8?

To rule out problems with the packet filter, disable iptables restrictions on both sides:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT; iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT; iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT; iptables -F FORWARD; iptables -F OUTPUT
```

Then when things begin working, you can start restricting traffic as you wish.

Your VM's iptables looks OK for ICMP traffic to go through, although you normally don't need to set FORWARD's policy to DROP unless you've enabled ip_forward.

On the host... that depends on the setup.

Comment: There was a problem with the Nat table thanks!